# Installed programs disappeared on Ubuntu Gnome 3

Tags: 14.04, gnome, virtualbox

I'm using ubuntu for over two years now. Two weeks ago, I installed Gnome 3, and I'm pretty satisfy, how it works. However, today I had very a strange situation.

When I tried to install new program, I tried to search it in Ubuntu software center. But then I realized, that it's missing (and I was using it two hours before that). Than, I realized, that Pidgin is also missing, as well as gnome-terminal, and installation of PHP, cURL. I'm not sure whether something else is missing, I hope not.

I tried to google what could be the reason. I didn't update my system since I installed it, so it's not something like that. Only thing that I installed today, is VirtualBox 4.3 for Ubuntu 14.04. But on the other hand, I'm not sure how that could mess up things I mentioned above.

Has anyone experienced this, or could guess what's the reason?

Thanks in advance, this really drove me crazy today.

**update**

Here's the output of /etc/apt/sources.list

http://pastie.org/9879807

Comment: post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` in the question.

Comment: hey, I just added it in updated section.

Comment: As you are saying gnome-terminal, php etc are missing. Waht is the output of `apt-cache policy php5 gnome-terminal` ?

Comment: yes, those were missing, but I installed it last night again. Pidgin was also missing, software-center, ruby-dev, mailcatcher. These things I noticed. I'm unsure how that could happen, and whether installation of virtualbox could mess it up. If I run command you pasted, it says that those are installed (cause I did it last night).